# Geth runing in docker occurs OOM

Tags: docker, geth

I use docker to run geth on Linux:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:04:39 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:13:39 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

Linux:
Linux version 4.4.0-1072-aws (buildd@lcy01-amd64-026) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ) #82-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 2 15:00:21 UTC 2018

geth:
Version: 1.8.20-unstable
Git Commit: f850123ec7500af732b73c2501f1ef36d80ee01d
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11.2
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

I use docker-compose to start up it, when it is running for a while, it use almost 50% memory, and it increases utill the process is down?  Why this happened? How can I fix this problem?

Thx